# Accessing HTML Format of Mapdeck Output

Tags: r, r-package, mapdeck

I am trying to share the output map from the mapdeck package, but it seems like users without the library installed cannot access the output html file. I am wondering if there's a way to share the map as a stand-alone HTML file? Thank you so much and take care!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: you're probably after the [`htmlwidgets::saveWidget`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/htmlwidgets/versions/1.5.4/topics/saveWidget) function

Comment: Make sure your mapdeck token is in the Rmarkdown file. I had the same problem, but it was resolved when I added the token.